# Inject ref into children from within a Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that I can change the `props` of `children` from within a Component using `React.Children.map()` and `React.cloneElement()`. But how would I inject a `ref` into children from within the Component class if I really need to? Is this even possible?

Comment: I would do that with a [HOC](http://jamesknelson.com/structuring-react-applications-higher-order-components/) that would programmatically calculated the `ref` for example and that would put it as `ref` in the `component`. But it force you to wrap the children Class in this HOC.

Comment: Pass `this.refs` as a prop to children and treat it like a normal prop

Comment: @DamienLeroux I'm not sure what you mean, but it sounds like I would have to change the child component classes in order get the injection done - which I would not really see as an alternative to the `Children.map/cloneElement` solution.

Comment: Can you just pass a function from the parent to the children and then have the children call that function. Then you could keep the ref where it belongs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that you can just use `React.Children.map()` and `React.cloneElement()` to inject a `ref` into children from within their parent Component. I made a mistake so it didn't work immediately.

But if you do it, you will receive an error and the code won't execute properly:

> **Warning**:
>   addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded.

https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html

Seems there is no legit way to get refs into children from within a component..